# AngularJS /Protactor : Error while running the protractor with the angular seed basic app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have cloned the angular-seed to my basic and try to run the protactor with the below command and got the below error.

npm run protractor

```
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor script 'protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Projects\LJ\npm-debug.log

C:\Projects\LJ>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running this one protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js ?